# sorted ItemFileReadStore list not pushed to dropdown menu // Dojo, ArcGIS

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo, key-value-store

this may be more a Dojo question than ArcGIS, but I am not sure if the Javascript API is related to this issue.

I am trying to alphabetically sort a Dojo store and show these items in a dropdown list, based on this example: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore.html

I can see in Firebug that my list is being sorted, but the sorted list is not displayed in the dropdown menu; the items there are still sorted by ObjectID.
I am not sure if I need to run my 'set' function differently, or if I am missing some code to replace the store list with the newly sorted list...ideas? // Jason

code:

```
    var dataItems = {
        identifier: 'name',
        label: 'name',
        items: values,

    };


var menuStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({ data: dataItems });  
menuStore.comparatorMap = {};

menuStore.comparatorMap['name']=function(a,b){
    if(a<b) return -1;
    if(a>b) return 1;
    return 0;
};

 var sortAttributes = [{attribute: "name", ascending: true}];
function completed(items, findResult){
    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
    {
        var value = menuStore.getValue(items[i], "name");
        console.log("Item ID: [" + menuStore.getValue(items[i], "name"));
        //// this console statement produces a sorted list in Firebug //// 
    }

}
function error(errData, request){
    console.log("Failed in sorting data.");
}

menuStore.fetch({onComplete: completed, onError: error, sort: sortAttributes});     
//  dijit.byId("schoolMenu").store = menuStore;   // may need this if an older version of API is used 

  dijit.byId("schoolMenu").set ("store", menuStore); // schoolMenu is dropdown menu     
} // end function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, since you're using the using the ComboBox, I'm reworking my answer so that it fits your question. Since you need to sort your data, we're going to modify the oncomplete command to load the sorted data into the menuStore, then create your combobox.

```
var dataItems = {
    identifier: 'name',
    label: 'name',
    items: values
};

var menuStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({ data: dataItems, clearOnClose: true});  
menuStore.comparatorMap = {};

menuStore.comparatorMap['name']=function(a,b){
    if(a<b) return -1;
    if(a>b) return 1;
    return 0;
};

var sortAttributes = [{attribute: "name", ascending: true}];

function completed(items, findResult){
    // change the ItemFileReadStore data items to the sorted list
    menuStore.data = {
        identifier: 'name',
        label: 'name',
        items: items
    };
    // close the data request on menuStore so that it's data can be reset
    menuStore.close();
    // close does not destroy data, but closes connection. Bringing up the combobox dropdown will reopen the connection.
}

function error(errData, request){
    console.log("Failed in sorting data.");
}

//  dijit.byId("schoolMenu").store = menuStore;   // may need this if an older version of API is used 

dijit.byId("schoolMenu").set ("store", menuStore); // schoolMenu is dropdown menu  

menuStore.fetch({onComplete: completed, onError: error, sort: sortAttributes});    
} // end function
```

Comment: Thanks for reply..I am using 3.1, which I beleive is also Dojo v1.8....the last line in the code above (I believe) sets the store?    dijit.byId("schoolMenu").set ("store", menuStore);      Is this method different than setStore?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please take a look at it.

Comment: Hello, I am finally coming back to this after many months! I am using ComboBoxes; I tried your combobox code, but I get an error saying "combobox.store.close is not a function" in Firebug.  I do not get an error if I comment out this one line...again, the list is sorted (I can see the sorted list in Firebug), but the combobox still displays the unsorted list. Thoughts?

Comment: I've continued working on this and still cannot get the right result...I can avoid the "combobox.store.close is not a function"  error by first setting the ComboBox store to menuStore before running your code above (then setting again after your code) , but then I get an error saying:" No JSON source data was provided as either URL or a nested Javascript object." ... I am having trouble understanding how the dropdown list will be populated if I clear it using clearAndClose.

Comment: I've updated my answer again. Hope this helps.

Comment: it worked!!!! thank you so much, this was driving me nuts!!!

Comment: Hello..I have been asked to revisit this project and make it device-responsive...and I have found the ComboBox works very poorly on iPhones and Androids.  Dijit.form.Select seems to work well on these phones however, but now I am back to an unsorted list! care to help again @raykendo?  I am trying various edits on the code you ave above (which works well btw), but no luck so far...